# $ does not always work in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is a Haskell code sample.

```
indentBrackets (c:rest) level
   | c=='('    = "\n" ++ (replicate level ' ') ++ [c]
                      ++ (indentBrackets rest (level+1))
   | c==')'    =  [c] ++ (indentBrackets rest (level-1))
   | c=='['    = "\n" ++ (replicate level ' ') ++ [c] 
                      ++ (indentBrackets rest (level+1))
   | c==']'    =  [c] ++ (indentBrackets rest (level-1))
   | otherwise =  [c] ++ (indentBrackets rest (level  ))

indentBrackets [] _ = ""
```

if I replace `otherwise = [c] ++ (indentBrackets rest (level))` with `otherwise = [c] ++ $ indentBrackets rest (level)`, I get

> src\Main.hs:182:25: parse error on input `$'

Should not that be ok?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that should not be ok.

The `$` operator is a perfectly ordinary infix operator: you can use it between two *expressions* (a function and its argument, respectively) or to form a *section*. The reason it is incorrect in

```
[c] ++ $ indentBrackets rest (level)   -- parse error on input `$'
```

is that the `++` operator is a perfectly ordinary infix operator: you can use it between two *expressions* (a prefix and its suffix, respectively) or to form a *section*. The trouble is that `[c] ++` is not an expression.

If you are unadvisedly determined to use `$` for this particular application, you can fix the problem by, indeed, making a section

```
([c] ++) $ indentBrackets rest (level)   -- should be fine
```

The extra set of brackets in `([c] ++)` delimits an operator section, being an underapplied infix operator, here yielding the function still awaiting the suffix.

Comment: More generally, it is a parse error to have two operators beside each other: `. .` `++ :` `/ *`

Answer (score 6):

Note that you don't need parens or `$` here *at all*: what you have is of the form

```
a ++ (f b (c))
```

Now, first, the parens around `c` do nothing, `c` is "atomical" anyway.

```
a ++ (f b c)
```

Next, remember how multiple arguments are handled in Haskell: *Currying*, i.e.

```
a ++ ((f b) c)
```

Let's use `g = f b` for a while...

```
a ++ (g c)
```

Ok, `g c` is a straightforward application, function / lambda-expression to value. Function application binds more tightly than any infix operator, so that's the same as

```
a ++ g c
```

Now bring back `f`

```
a ++ (f b) c
```

remove the currying brackets again, and you end up with

```
a ++ f b c
```

or, for your example,

```
[c] ++ indentBrackets rest level
```

If we apply it to your entire code:

```
indentBrackets (c:rest) level
   | c=='('    = "\n" ++ replicate level ' ' ++ [c]
                      ++ indentBrackets rest (level+1)
   | c==')'    =  [c] ++ indentBrackets rest (level-1)
   | c=='['    = "\n" ++ replicate level ' ' ++ [c] 
                      ++ indentBrackets rest (level+1)
   | c==']'    =  [c] ++ indentBrackets rest (level-1)
   | otherwise =  [c] ++ indentBrackets rest  level
```

Incidentally, I'd trim this down a bit:

```
indentBrackets (c:rest) level
   | c `elem` "(["  = "\n" ++ replicate level ' '
                        ++ c : indentBrackets rest (level+1)
   | c `elem` ")]"  =  c : indentBrackets rest (level-1)
   | otherwise =  c : indentBrackets rest  level
```